# Neural Network training accuracy better than validation accuracy, using the same samples. Shouldn't they converge?

Tags: neural-networks, validation, accuracy

I'm training a neural network to classify the MNIST digits. For this, I am using [this mnist library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mnist) which states:

> It includes 10000 different samples of mnist digits.

And:

> Both sets [training and validation] are shuffled, and there are no samples repeated in both sets.

So, what I'm doing is create a 8000 samples training set, and a 2000 validation set, train against the first one, validate against the second one, and measuring accuracy in both. With each epoch I create new training/validation sets.

Witch each training run, I can see the training set accuracy increasing, reaching +98%. But validation set accuracy gets stuck at around 88% consistently.

So my question is, given the fact that both training and validation are randomly selected in each iteration from the same total samples (the 10.000 samples cited above), how can validation accuracy and training accuracies converge to different values?

At the end of the day, with each iteration, each new 8000/2000 pair would contain a   large number of overlapping samples with sets of previous iterations, specially if taken out of only 10.000 total. I mean, it says that validation set has no repeated sets with the training set, but that's only for each training/validation creation. Why does validation behave differently, and not converge to training accuracy in the long run?

Comment: I think this is because of [overfitting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overfitting), you are learning your training data too well and it doesn't generalise to unseen validation data

Comment: @DirkNachbar yes but, validation data is just another sample from the same database, so essentially is not different from training data. With 10.000 total samples and 8000/2000 traing/validation samples in each run, I should be basically training and validating over the same data after a number of iterations, right? that's what I don't understand.

Comment: @jotadepicas You mean each epoch you shuffle from the whole datasets, so the validation data may appear in next train data? Why doing this?

Comment: @danche Yes. It seems that's how this nodejs mnist library works, AFAIK. Regardless if doing it makes sense or not (I see your point), *IF* I do it, shouldn't accuracies converge to the same number?

Comment: @jotadepicas Did you add some reg or dropout layer? A possible explanation is that after some initial training the model converged, so you get 88% validation acc. But later, each time you train your model, you overfit on the specific training data, it makes the validation acc stucked.

Comment: @danche reg or dropout layer? not sure I know what you mean. my network is 784-15-10, what's a reg or dropout layer?

Comment: @jotadepicas Sorry, I mean did you add some parameters regulation or dropout layers to avoid overfitting.

Comment: @danche no I didn't. Before trying to tackle possible overfitting, I wanted to understand why this was happening, given that training and validation samples would be almost the same. I'm starting to think maybe this library I'm using has a bug, or it's intended to be used differently...

Comment: @jotadepicas It is possible. But I think more possible is like I said before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it was suggested in some of the comments, **this seems to be a case of overfitting**. However, what was counter-intuitive IMHO is the behavior of [the MNIST library I am using](https://github.com/cazala/mnist).

If you take [a closer look to the library code](https://github.com/cazala/mnist/blob/master/src/mnist.js#L147), you can see that every time you call `mnist.set(8000,2000)` to generate a training set of 8000 samples, and a validation set of 2000 samples, **it generates the exact same two sets every time**. The samples are **shuffled within each set** and after the total sets are partitioned in trainingSet<->validationSet, but the first 8000 samples are training, and the last 2000 are validation, that does not change. At first, I thought the library would randomize the total sets so each subsequent `mnist.set` invocation would create a different trainingSet/validationSet pair (regardless of internal randomization in each set), but that was not the case.

In other words, it doesn't make sense, with this library, to make something like this (in pseudo-code):

```
for each epoch {
   aSet = mnist.set(8000, 2000)
   trainingSet = aSet.training
   validationSet = aSet.validation

   doTraining(trainingSet)
   doValidation(validationSet)
}
```

The code above would produce the same `aSet.training` and `aSet.validation` every time, only that each set would be randomized, but never mixed with each other.

Having clarified this, now I can see that I am training always with the same training set, and validating always with the same validation set, so I am not using "the same samples" for validation and training as I thought I was.